# Xamarin Android: Calling Native Library Methods of SO file Crashing with SIGSEGV

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am working on Android with Xamarin Studio
I have added the SO file into libs and followed the steps described in the Xamarin docs.
My application is able to build and running device But during calling a native method from SO file shared library I am getting the fallowing exception

```
   Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper managed-to-native)_init (string,int) <IL 0x00038, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt]   at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.cbf4c5d8-8ed7-41b7-954a-1802bf0daaf0 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr) <IL 0x0001d, 0x00053>[mono-rt]   at (wrapper native-to-managed) object.cbf4c5d8-8ed7-41b7-954a-1802bf0daaf0 (intptr,intptr,int,intptr) <IL 0x00026, 0xffffffff>
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.


[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x766566d3 (code=1)
```

I would like to know why the above crash coming how to resolve it?